# How do I call a "write file" method in another class?

Tags: java, android

In my Android application I want to have one class handling all "write/read to textfile" actions. So I simply can call the method i want in my readUserFile.java file. But my methods will not work in that file?

Creating a file works fine in my MainActivity, but will not work in my readUserFile class. I have tried to make my create() method static but than openFileOutput will not work. I have also tried to make readUserFile a static object of itself and then call the create method from another method but didn't work. Mabye it have something with context to do that i don't rely understand?

```
public class readUserFile extends Application {

String filename = "users.txt";
boolean exist = false;

public void create(){
    File users = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),filename);
    if(!users.exists()){
        String fileContents = "Admin=Admin=99999";
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        try {
            outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(fileContents.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
            exist = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            exist = false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

readUserFile userFile = new readUserFile();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){

    if(userFile.exist == true){
        Toast.makeText(this, "!!!FILE EXISTS!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        userFile.create();
        Toast.makeText(this, "File Created "+ i + " "+ userFile.exist, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected it to not be so bloody hard, and not the app to crash as soon as i start it.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling .exist incorrectly. Make **users** private to the class and create a new method in readUserFile that returns the file:

```
public File getFile()
{
    return users;
}
```

then in MainActivity your if statement would be:

```
if(userFile.getFile().exists() == true){
    Toast.makeText(this, "!!!FILE EXISTS!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else{
    userFile.create();
    Toast.makeText(this, "File Created "+ i + " "+ userFile.getFile().exists(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```